# MySQL query to generate columns from row data but within the same table?

Tags: mysql

I'm learning to design a table the way the pros do it, but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

I have a table where I store a primary ID in id with parent_id referring to the parent, also in the same table

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p_name` longtext NOT NULL,
  `p_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `p_brand` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `p_version` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`search_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT;

+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| id     | p_name   | p_code   | P_brand  |  p_version| parent_id |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1      |   Alpha  |    S001  |     X    |         1 |         6 |
| 2      |   Alpha  |    S032  |     X    |         2 |         6 |
| 3      |   Alpha  |    S403  |     X    |         3 |         6 |
| 6      |   Prism  |    S004  |          |         1 |           |
| 6      |   Prism  |    S044  |          |         2 |           |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+ ----------+
```

I've looked into pivot table but it doesn't fit what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm looking to generate a report that displays the version for each id without using a lookup table.

```
+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| id     | p_name   | version 1| version 2| version 3 |  parent_id| 
+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1      |   Alpha  |    S001  |   S032   |   S43   1 |         6 |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+ ----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the p_name, p_brand and p_parent_id are common to each version it looks like you should probably split your table into three -

```
products (id, name, brand_id, parent_id)
versions (id, product_id, code, version)
brands (id, brand).
```

Based on your current structure for the catalog table you could use a crosstab query like this -

```
SELECT
    `p_name`,
    MAX(IF(`p_version` = 1, `p_code`)) AS `version 1`,
    MAX(IF(`p_version` = 2, `p_code`)) AS `version 2`,
    MAX(IF(`p_version` = 3, `p_code`)) AS `version 3`,
    `parent_id`
FROM `catalog`
GROUP BY `p_name`, `parent_id`
```

If you use my proposed table structure this would change to something like this -

```
SELECT
    `p`.`name`,
    MAX(IF(`v`.`version` = 1, `v`.`code`)) AS `version 1`,
    MAX(IF(`v`.`version` = 2, `v`.`code`)) AS `version 2`,
    MAX(IF(`v`.`version` = 3, `v`.`code`)) AS `version 3`,
    `p`.`parent_id`
FROM `products` `p`
INNER JOIN `brands` `b`
    ON `p`.brand_id` = `b`.`id`
INNER JOIN `versions` `v`
    ON `p`.`id` = `v`.`product_id`
GROUP BY `p`.`name`, `p`.`parent_id`
```

Comment: This is great. Looks like I need to redesign the whole table, instead of using a hierarchy in the same table. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you are suggesting here is for a "Tree" like data structure where the concept is that everything resides within a heirarcheal data model from a parent to a child.

Think of having data in only one place.  For instance, the string "S001" if it going to be used by multiple records, then creating a star based schema or even more complex a snow flake schema would be a better choice.

Comment: Star based schema looks like what I should be using here.